# I/O Dialog Boxes with Arithmatic

Tags: java, input, dialog, output

My assignment is to write a program that prompts the user to input a weight in kilograms, and outputs the weight in pounds to two decimal places.

Here is what I got so far and while it worked before I started on the dialog boxes, I was able to get the input box to correctly work.  But not the output.  I tried following a thread I found on here but got even more confused

I know I screwed up somewhere but don't know where.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

     //  the above allows the above to be important to allow the code below to function

     public class WeightConversion { // File name 

     public static void main (String[] args)
     {

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

     double weight_in_kilograms; 

     double weight_in_pounds;

     String stringInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Weight in Kilograms");

     // This allows the dialog box to pop up and input the required data

     System.out.print("Your Weight in Kilograms: "); // This will print the number you input

     System.out.print(stringInput); 


     weight_in_kilograms = sc.nextDouble (); // From my understandingf this will all the data to be displayed as an interger

     weight_in_pounds = weight_in_kilograms*2.2; // this is the equation for the conversion


     sc.close ();  // This closes the above and allows the conversion to happen, from my understanding


    System.out.printf("Weight in Pounds: " + "%.2f" + "\n",  weight_in_pounds);

    // This will allow it to print to rwo decimal places

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null "Your Weight in Pounds is: ", "Display Message" JOptionPane. INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

//   This is I think what it should be to pop up another dialog box with the conversion.  
//   But I tried for a while and changed things and couldn't get it to work.


}
}
```

Comment: This `weight_in_kilograms = sc.nextDouble ();` needs to change, as you're no longer taking input from the console, but from the GUI. Something like `weight_in_kilograms = Double.parseDouble(stringInput);`. Also, as a general rule, don't close a `Scanner` which is using `System.in`, this closes the underlying stream, making it impossible to use `System.in` again during the current run cycle

Comment: You can use `String.format` to format a `String` value, just like you're `printf` statement, which means you could do something like, `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Weight in Pounds: " + "%.2f" + "\n",  weight_in_pounds), "Display Message" JOptionPane. INFORMATION_MESSAGE);`

Comment: Thanks you so much for the info.  I am still new to all this and it's pretty confusing to me.  I will try this once I get to a computer again.